# Mapping caps to ctrl doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-layout, configuration, capslock

I decided I want to have my caps-lock key behave as ctrl key, so I added `XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"` to my `/etc/defaults/keyboard` file.
This file as of now has these contents:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier"
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Also, after reboot `$ setxkbmap -query` returns

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
variant:    nodeadkeys
options:    caps:ctrl_modifier
```

as expected (it is `pc105` since it is originally a german keyboard).

However, for whatever reason this doesn't set the caps behavior as I wanted...
If I try to manually run `$ setxkbmap -option "caps:ctrl_modifier"` I get 
`Error loading new keyboard description`; and no matter what option I write I get the same error.
I also noticed if I run `$ setxkbmap -layout us` on my own afterwards, then `$ setxkbmap -option "caps:ctrl_modifier"` works again and caps now works as expected.

**Question:** what did I do wrong and how do I do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the root of my problems: it is using an extra keyboard (maybe this has to do with the fact that it is wireless, not sure about that).

If after manually fixing the problem as described I then re-plug the keyboard - I get into the same situation with `$ setxkbmap -option` not working and caps not behaving.

Apparently the config is read before the keyboard is detected or something like that. Now the question would be how to fix this, but I guess googling will help.

For now I can just write a tiny script with

```sh
setxkbmap -layout us -option caps:ctrl_modifier
```

inside, and run that after restart (or maybe even put that in `.bashrc`).

Comment: Hi, What is your Ubuntu version? This should not be in a long way.. you can simply run a command in terminal and that should set it permanent...

Comment: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['caps:ctrl_modifier']`

Comment: this command should set xkb-options to `ctrl_modifier` but if you have previously set any other xkb-options you should add this value adjacent to that which you get from get command.. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"`

Comment: @PRATAP I got Ubuntu 18.04. The `gsettings` version seems to not work for me - after re-plugging the keyboard I yet again get to square one.

Comment: with keyboard plugged in what is the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @PRATAP it's `['caps:ctrl_modifier']`.

Comment: I think you need to undo the changes you made as you explained in your Q & A.. gsettings output says your capslock key is ctrl..

Comment: my laptops keyboard contrl key is damaged.. I do reinstall ubuntu 18.04 several times bcoz of practicing and breaking the system.. every time I reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 the first command I run is `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['caps:ctrl_modifier']"`

Comment: @PRATAP thanks for your help, the command is written down and saved for the times then things work again :)

Comment: in my opinion if nothing is disturbed relating to xkboptions or keyboard file from /etc/default/ gsettings command should work..